# How to design table when calculating assortivity coefficient

Tags: r, igraph

When I calculate the assortativity coefficient with assortativity.nominal(graph, types) - how do I have to design the table then?

I have these columns:

```
Ego, Alter, Profit_Interest_Ego, Profit_Interest_Alter
1, 101, 1, 2
2, 203, 1, 1
...
```

So, "graph" is column *Ego* & column *Alter* - right?
And "types" are *Profit_Interest_Ego* & *Profit_Interest_Alter*. - but how do I merge these two columns into one factor so that I can use assortativity.nominal(graph, **types**)?

Comment: Welcome to SO!,  please mention the library(ies)  required for your problem

Comment: When asking for help please be sure to include a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data and the code you've tried. Include error messages or describe where you are getting stuck.